# Zend Framework funciona com Nginx (sem apache)?

Tags: php, nginx

Tenho um projeto desenvolvido em zf2 e atualmente uso uma hospedagem compartilhada com Apache, mas vou migrar para o VPS da Digital Ocean e vou configurar o servidor com Nginx, pois tem melhor desempenho.

Ou seja, ao invés de Apache, vou utilizar Nginx.

Será que meu sistema desenvolvido em ZF2 irá funcionar normalmente no Nginx ou terei que fazer alguma modificação?

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta de todos, pelo que entendi vai funcionar normal desde que todos os módulos necessários estejam habilitados, só não explicaram aonde fica o arquivo de configuração para habilitar os módulos

Comment: Mas você não perguntou isto, a sua  pergunta só fala de ngnix e apache não vi você perguntar dos modulos zf2.

Comment: Minha pergunta inicial foi sobre funcionar com nginx, mas as respostas evoluíram para ativar os módulos necessários, apenas gostaria de saber onde ativa estes módulos, se é igual um arquivo .htacess onde passa algumas configurações, abração

Comment: Entendo, mas é então você deve editar a pergunta, amigo por favor entenda não somos um fórum e sim um site de Q&A, recomendo que leia o máximo do http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help, espero que entenda isto como uma critica construtiva :) - ps: Vou tentar editar a resposta assim que possível pra dar detalhes sobre os módulos (componentes) do zf2

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado, esta é minha primeira pergunta e estou aprendendo como funciona, aliás a comunidade está de parabéns, muito prestativa!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que as únicas dependências do Zf2 sejam em relação ao PHP e ao `mod_rewrite` (se for usar *urls amigáveis*) como citado no **[próprio manual do Zf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/ref/requirements.html)!**.

Se for usar as *urls amigáveis* (o que não é uma obrigação) então terá terá que fazer modificações, já que o arquivo .htaccess não irá funcionar no Ngnix, pois ele é um documento do Apache, no entanto o Ngnix assim como o Apache permite criar *urls amigaveis*

Provavelmente você pode usar o `try_files`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

### Documentação do Ngnix:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/zend/#time-for-nginx

É provável que consiga fazer tudo com o *Ngnix* que iria fazer no *Apache*, no entanto de outra maneira.

Uma página que pode lhe ajudar a converter o seu arquivo .htacces: http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Ela não é tão inteligente quanto "uma pessoa", mas ajuda a quebrar um galho, no entanto recomendo dar uma estudada no *Ngnix*, ele pode ser tão simples quanto o Apache.

## Requerimentos:

A pergunta aqui fala apenas de dependências sobre do Zf2 em relação ao Ngnix e não havia a necessidade de postar sobre o php em si, mas irei citar as dependências PHP como um adicional que pode auxiliar outras pessoas com duvidas:

- PHP 5.2.4 ou superior

Extensões PHP usadas pelos componentes do *Zend*:

Nem todas extensões serão necessárias, isto vai depender do componente

- `apc`, `Soft`, `bcmath`, `bitset`, `bz2`, `calendar`, `com_dotnet`, `ctype`, `ZendGData`, `ZendHttpClient`, `ZendPdf`, `ZendRestClient`, `ZendRestServer`, `ZendSearchLucene`, `Zend_Uri`, `Zend_Validate`, `curl`, `date`, `dba`, `dbase`, `dom`, `Zend_Dom`, `Zend_Feed`, `ZendGData`, `ZendLogFormatterXml`, `ZendRestServer`, `Zend_Soap`, `ZendSearchLucene`, `ZendServiceAmazon`, `ZendServiceDelicious`, `ZendServiceFlickr`, `Zend_XmlRpc`, `exif`, `fbsql`, `fdf`, `filter`, `ftp`, `gd`, `ZendPdf`, `gettext`, `gmp`, `hash`, `ibm_db2`, `iconv`, `ZendLocaleFormat`, `Zend_Mime`, `ZendPdf`, `ZendSearchLucene`, `ZendServiceAudioscrobbler`, `ZendServiceFlickr`, `ZendValidateHostname`, `ZendValidateStringLength`, `ZendXmlRpcClient`, `igbinary`, `imap`, `informix`, `interbase`, `json`, `ZendSerializerAdapterJson`, `ldap`, `libxml`, `mbstring`, `mcrypt`, `memcache`, `mhash`, `mime_magic`, `ming`, `msql`, `mssql`, `mysql`, `mysqli`, `ncurses`, `oci8`, `odbc`, `openssl`, `pcntl`, `pcre`, `pdo`, `pdo_dblib`, `pdo_firebird`, `pdo_mssql`, `pdo_mysql`, `pdo_oci`, `pdo_pgsql`, `pdo_sqlite`, `pgsql`, `posix`, `pspell`, `readline`, `recode`, `Reflection`, `Zend_Filter`, `ZendFilterInput`, `Zend_Json`, `Zend_Log`, `ZendRestServer`, `ZendServerReflection`, `Zend_Validate`, `Zend_View`, `ZendXmlRpcServer`, `session`, `Zend_Session`, `shmop`, `SimpleXML`, `Zend_Feed`, `ZendRestClient`, `ZendSerializerAdapterWddx`, `ZendServiceAudioscrobbler`, `Zend_Soap`, `Zend_XmlRpc`, `Soft`, `soap`, `Zend_Soap`, `sockets`, `SPL`, `SQLite`, `standard`, `sybase`, `sysvmsg`, `sysvsem`, `sysvshm`, `tidy`, `tokenizer`, `wddx`, `xml`, `ZendTranslatorAdapterTmx`, `ZendTranslatorAdapterXliff`, `XMLReader`, `xmlrpc`, `XMLWriter`, `xsl`, `zip`, `zlib`, `ZendFilterCompress`

Comment: Não entendi o negativo na minha resposta, até aonde sei as dependências do Zf2 estão no php e não no Apache, com exceção do `mod_rewrite` (que pode ser ou não usado), se existe algo de errado com a resposta comente por favor, pra que eu possa melhorar ou deletar. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Não vejo porque poderia dar algum problema. Servidores HTTP nada mais fazem do que responder a um acesso por meio de uma determinada URL, através de uma determinada porta, com o conteúdo HTTP desejado.

O que você precisa verificar é se todos os módulos que você precisa para o projeto estejam habilitados, e que o virtual host esteja corretamente configurado. Geralmente os módulos incluem suporte à linguagem desejada (no caso, PHP), escrita de URL, SSH, dentre outros. Configuração de virtual host também costuma ser tranquila.